# Show multiple images in ViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, uikit

I have tried the following code to load multiple images in sequence in my ViewController.

```
import SwiftUI
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var ctrl = MainPageController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 4.0)
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
        var backgroundImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: width, height: height))
        backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "loading")
        backgroundImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        self.view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5.0)
        backgroundImageView.removeFromSuperview()
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5.0)
        backgroundImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: width, height: height))
        backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "loading1")
        backgroundImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        self.view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5.0)
        backgroundImageView.removeFromSuperview()
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MainViewSegue", sender: self)
```

But I see only the second image.  I want to load the first image, show it for about 5 seconds, then replace it with the second image, display that for 5 seconds.  I have removed the image from the Launch.storyboard. Currently I cannot see any image. The self.performSegue works. How do I fix this problem?

Thanks

Vyasa

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating new image views. If you goal is to simply change the image after 5 seconds you can simplify this code to be something more like:

```swift
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Load 1")
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
self.view.addSubview(imageView)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
    // the code in this block will only execute after 5 seconds
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Load 2")
}
```